# unload module sr_mod gives me an error : rmmod: ERROR: Module sr_mod is in use

Tags: kernel

```
# lsmod | grep -i sr_mod
sr_mod                 22416  1
cdrom                  42556  1 sr_mod
```

but its not used by any other module

How can I find out that this module is used by which proccess or module?

---

I want to unload the `sr_mod` with this command:
`rmmod sr_mod` 
and I get this error: 
`rmmod: ERROR: Module sr_mod is in use` 
************************************ 
`#modinfo sr_mod | grep depends` 
`depends:        cdrom` 
************************************** 
`#rmmod cdrom` 
`rmmod: ERROR: Module cdrom is in use by: sr_mod` 
************************************** 
`#modinfo cdrom | grep depends` 
`depends:`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after:

```
modinfo sr_mod
```

It'll hopefully give you all the information you need.

Comment: Yes but not the information about which module uses `sr_mod`

Comment: Why not? Check out `modinfo sr_mod | grep depends` which yield `depends:        scsi_mod,cdrom` in my case.

Comment: because `sr_mod` depends `cdrom`... so for unloading `cdrom` I must first unload `sr_mod` and in my case it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Can you edit the question and append the output from unloading `cd_rom`?

Answer (score -1):

Try this one-
lsmod cdrom | grep cdrom

It should display “sr_mod” as dependency.

Run below command to remove cdrom module.

## modprobe -r sr_mod